# Why does not capitalizing the class name cause a compiler error here?

Tags: groovy

This Groovy script runs fine:

```
println 0;
class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(int j) {};
   public MyClass method() {return this};
}
```

This one fails with a compilation error ("unexpected token: public at line: 5, column: 4")

```
println 0;
class myClass
{
   public myClass(int j) {};
   public myClass method() {return this};
}
```

The only difference is the capitalization of the class name. I know the convention is for class names to be capitalized, but I thought it was just a convention. What exactly causes the compile error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [Groovy mailing list thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Class-with-lower-case-first-letter-td356622.html) from 2008, where a similar question was posed, Paul King explained:

> Yes, the grammar currently looks for uppercase types only in declarations  (apart from the primitive types).

In a more recent, [unresolved Groovy JIRA ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6209) regarding lowercase class names, blackdrag comments that:

> The problem is that in Groovy (unlike Java) variable names, method names and class names can share a context, making it ambiguous.

Barring a deeper exploration of the tokenizer, I'll just chalk this up as another minor inconsistency between Java and Groovy due to Groovy's syntax flexibility. And instead of thoroughly implementing a way to tell if a token is a type or method name in this context, Groovy takes a short cut and only assumes it can be a type name if the token matches a primitive or begins with a capital letter, as conventional Java types would.

Comment: You say "_another minor inconsistency between Java and Groovy due to Groovy's syntax flexibility_" but I'd say Groovy is merely **shifting the inflexibility** from one place to another. Groovy is becoming more _inflexible_ in not allowing lowercase class names, the price paid for becoming more _flexible_ in allowing class names to share a context with variable and method names.

Comment: Good point. I suppose that's one benefit of not having a formal language spec--you can shift inflexibility to areas where its more tolerable for it to exist from a practicality standpoint. When Groovy started, they used its Java syntax compatibility as a selling point. Nowadays, they've seemed to de-emphasize that aspect and sell Groovy on its other features (optional static type checking, DSL creation, functional programming,...), especially since Java 8 dropped.

Comment: just want to add that this "inflexibility" exists for a long time already, reaching back to the Strachan time. The comment on the JIRA ticket I made back then was more related to the user being able to write "foo = bar" and the compiler not being able to clearly see if bar is supposed to be a variable (possibly dynamic) or a class. Normally you can easily bypass problems like this with "import as". But the original question above sounds like a bug to me actually.